# I'm trying to use a E18-D80NK but the output is always 1

Tags: arduino-uno

i'm trying to use a E18-D80NK sensor with arduino but the output is always at 1, i really don't understand why
This is my code :

```
int irPin2 = 8;// define pint 2 for sensor

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);// setup Serial Monitor to display information
  pinMode(irPin2, INPUT);// define pin as Input  sensor
}

void loop() {
  int out = digitalRead(irPin2);// read the sensor 

    Serial.println(out);

  delay(250);
 // E18-D80NK Obstacle Sensor 
}
```

and circuit: [image: E18-D80NK Obstacle Sensor]

Comment: What do you see when you attach an oscilloscope or a volt meter to the sensor? Does the LED on the sensor flash when you place an object in front of the sensor?

Comment: Unfurtunately i have not this facility but on arduino terminal i see all the time 1 in output

Comment: A cheap digital voltmeter (better: estimator) or an inexpensive DSO138 style oscilloscope will save your head from time to time...

Comment: do you see any error in my project? this is the datasheet http://www.energiazero.org/arduino_sensori/wiring%20the%20e18-d80nk%20infrared%20distance%20ranging%20sensor.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities for what is wrong:

1) The wiring may be wrong: the datasheet you reference lists two types (red,black,yellow) and (blue,brown,black) but in your pic it looks like you have (blue, grey, black).  I wouldn't assume the color coding of the sensor wires are correct.

2) The "pull-up" resister mentioned in the data sheet referenced (and included schematic) is not functioning as a pull-up resistor.  I would get rid of the resistor and plug the digital-output wire of the sensor directly into the arduino input.   Also, try configuring the input with pull-up like:  pinMode(irPin2, INPUT_PULLUP);
The Arduino inputs are high impedance and typically do not need a series resistor.

Comment: Your second point is probably the problem. The wiring diagram in the datasheet is wrong. The signal line needs a pull-up (either internal or external).

Comment: Thank you for your help, i tried to plug the digital-putput wire directly into the arduino input but it doesn't work, the output is still at "1" every time i put an object in front of the sensor

Comment: Then possibility 1) above is likely the issue.   There are not that many combinations so with trial and error you should be able to find the correct wiring arrangement.

Comment: i tried different combinations but that doesn't work.. i think that my sensor could be defective

Comment: Or perhaps the sensitivity adjustment on the sensor needs adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

Your sensor pull low and not high, normally they pull high , I did however buy a few that is permanently on and then switch of ( pull low) when object in range.