# Trying to interface E18-D80NK sensor but the output is always one - what to do?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

[I'm trying to use a E18-D80NK but the output is always 1](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/75846/im-trying-to-use-a-e18-d80nk-but-the-output-is-always-1/81953#81953)

Referring to the above link. I am facing the same problem. But unfortunately there is no solution in the given link. My code goes as follows:

```
#define SENSOR 2 // define pint 2 for sensor
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);// setup Serial Monitor to display information
  pinMode(SENSOR, INPUT_PULLUP);// define pin as Input  sensor
}

void loop() {
  
  int L =digitalRead(SENSOR);// read the sensor 
  
      if(L == 0){
    Serial.println(" Obstacle detected");
   
     }else{

     Serial.println("  === All clear");
  
     }
  delay(500);
 
}
```

Wiring:

```
Brown = 5V
Black = INPUT
Blue = Gnd
```

This is always giving me '=== All clear' as output. Also, would like to mention that, I bought a new sensor recently. Now i doubt is it a defective piece.
Could you please help.

Comment: your post needs to be self-contained ... the linked post could get deleted

Comment: Try connecting the sensor's power and measure the voltage of the input pin (disconnected from the arduino) with a voltmeter. If that works, then your sensor is good. Try then with the pullup disabled.

Comment: the datasheet has the pullup resistor incorrectly connected ... the note next to the wire color chart is correct ... you are using internal pullup, so you do not need an external resistor

Comment: please remove the `ir` tag ... your question is not about IR

Comment: Thank you, jsotola for your correction and reply. I tried what you suggested still no results.

Comment: Thank you, Mat for you reply. I just want a little clarification. I did not understand, what do you mean by 'sensor's power'? However, I simply tried with pullup disabled, but did not work.